# Change ip of a subscription domain on plesk12

Tags: plesk

When I create a new subscription it uses a new ip and I'm not able to put to this new subscription one ip used in another subscription. Is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

By default all new IP addresses has type "Dedicated", you can check and change it to "Shared" in Tools & Settings > IP Addresses > choose desired IP address